# snapshotChanges not retrieving updated data

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am fetching latest 5 records from collection `chats` on `ngOnInit()` which is working perfectly fine. Now when I add  **new record** I want that to come in the list. In order to achieve this I used `.snapshotChanges()` but it is not updating that added record as expected.

**home.ts**

```
        ngOnInit() {
        //##fetch first 5 starts
        this.firestore.collection('chats' , ref => ref
    .limit(5) 
    .orderBy('entryDate', 'desc')
    )
    .snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe(response => {
    if(!response.length){
      console.log("no data available");
      return false;
    }
    this.firstInResponse = response[0].payload.doc;
    this.lastInResponse = response[response.length - 1].payload.doc;
    for(let item of response){
      var data = item.payload.doc.data();
      this.tableData.push(data);
    }

    }) //##fetch first 5 ends
}
```

**home.html**

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-textarea placeholder="Type a comment..." [(ngModel)]="val1"></ion-textarea>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-button (click)="sendcomment()">
    <ion-icon size="small" slot="icon-only" name="add"></ion-icon>
    &nbsp;Post comment
  </ion-button>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor = "let item of tableData; let i = index;">
    <ion-label>{{item.message}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>{{item.fromName}}</ion-label>
    <!-- <ion-label>{{item.chat_date}}</ion-label> -->
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Screenshot of `home.html`:

[image]

### Edit 1

showing `console.log` values:

I have messages from **1** to **22** in db, on **1st** time when page loads `console.log` shows *0 to 4* `5 entries` - `18,19,20,21,22`.

After adding `23` as new entry in db now `console.log` array shows *0 to 14* `15 entries` -

**18,19,20,21,22    -- this came on ngOnInit
19,20,21,22,23
19,20,21,22,23**

Screenshot attached:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried console logging inside of the subscribe?, tell us what it's printing and also paste here dump from console window of browser if there is any.

Comment: adding `this.tableData=[]` before pushing data in array sorted everything

Comment: So now the problem is solved right

Comment: yes, resolved..